# Proving $T$ is an isometry iff it preserves the inner product

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, solution-verification, euclidean-geometry, isometry

I'm working on an exercise in the text and am proving the following statement:

> Suppose $T: \mathbb{R}^{n} \to \mathbb{R}^{n}$ is a linear transform. Prove that T is an isometry if and only if $T(v) \cdot T(w) = v \cdot w$

I'm currently working to prove the reverse statement and would like some clarification on a step, and potentially some guidance if my approach or any of my calculations are incorrect. I reference $2$ parts of the following proposition in my proof thus far

> Proposition: $\forall u,v,w \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$ and $a \in \mathbb{R}$ we have
>
> 1. $v \cdot v \geq 0$
> 2. $v \cdot w = w \cdot v$
> 3. $(av + u) \cdot w = a(v \cdot w) + (u \cdot w)$

---

**The proof (thus far)**

Assume $T$ is an isometry. This means $\lvert T(v) - T(w)\rvert = \lvert v-w \rvert$. We have
$$\lvert T(v)-T(w) \rvert = \sqrt{[T(v)-T(w)] \cdot [T(v)-T(w)]} $$
By part $3$ of the proposition we have
$$\sqrt{T(v) \cdot T(v) - T(v) \cdot T(w) - T(w) \cdot T(v) + T(w) \cdot T(w)}$$
Now by part $2$ of the proposition we obtain
$$\sqrt{T(v) \cdot T(v) - 2T(v) \cdot T(w) + T(w) \cdot T(w)}$$
Which is
$$\lvert T(v) \rvert + \sqrt{-2T(v) \cdot T(w)} + \lvert T(w) \rvert = \lvert T(v) \rvert + i \sqrt{2T(v) \cdot T(w)} + \lvert T(w) \rvert$$

But, since $T$ is an isometry we have $\lvert T(v) - T(w) \rvert = \lvert v-w \rvert$ and by a similar calculation for $\lvert v-w \rvert$ we have:
$$\lvert T(v) \rvert + i \sqrt{2T(v) \cdot T(w)} + \lvert T(w) \rvert = \lvert v \rvert + i \sqrt{2v \cdot w} + \lvert w \rvert$$

---

Now at this part I'm a little confused. What I would like to do is claim that $\lvert T(v) \rvert = \lvert v \rvert$ and the same for the vector $w$ to get
$$i \sqrt{2T(v) \cdot T(w)} = i \sqrt{2v \cdot w}$$
Where then I could cancel the $i$'s and the square roots (then the $2$'s) and show that the assumption that $T$ is an isometry directly implies that inner products are preserved. But I don't know if I can claim that$\lvert T(v) \rvert = \lvert v \rvert$ since isometries preserve distances and they don't say anything directly about preserving the length of vectors.

Comment: Note $\sqrt{a + b + c} \neq \sqrt{a} + \sqrt{b} + \sqrt{c}$. You should instead square both sides of the equation $|T(v) - T(w)| = |v - w|$ and simplify.

Comment: Strongly recommened to use polarization identity. See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polarization_identity

Comment: @Kobe Should I square that exact form of the equation? Or square after distributing. I squared after distributing and right now I'm left with $$T(v) \cdot T(v) - 2T(v) \cdot T(w) + T(w) \cdot T(w) = v \cdot v - 2v \cdot w + w \cdot w$$

Comment: You have $T(v) \cdot T(v) = |T(v)|^2 = |v|^2 = v \cdot v$, and similarly $T(w) \cdot T(w) = w\cdot w$. So you can simplify even further.

Comment: @kobe That's what I was hoping to do but I don't see that from the assumption that we're working with. That would go back to my question in my post: If we're assuming $T$ is an isometry, that means that $T$ preserves distances, but does that then mean that we can assume that $T$ preserves lengths of vectors as well?

Comment: Since $T$ preserves distance, in particular the distance from $T(v)$ to $T(0)$ is the same as the distance from $v$ to $0$, i.e., $|T(v) - T(0)| = |v|$. By linearity of $T$, $T(0) = 0$ so we must have $|T(v)| = |v|$.

Comment: @kobe Ah, okay that makes perfect sense. Thank you!

Comment: Note: use `\lvert T(v) \rvert` instead of `\mid` to get proper whitespace around norm bars.

Comment: @SammyBlack, Will do! I just looked at your edit. I appreciate the formatting tips.